# I keep getting bad verification code when requesting github access token

Tags: python, vue.js, authentication, github, github-api

I am using auth0-vue for user authentication. I have added the github login connection in my auth0 console, selected the permission to view the user repo. I have also created the github auth0 application in my developer settings and the login/permession process in my frontend work as expected. Then when the code and state is returned after the user logs in I am sending the code to my back end server to make the following request for the github access token:

```
def get_github_token(code: str, state: str = None):
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("github.com")

    payload = ""

    conn.request("POST", f"/login/oauth/access_token?code={code}&client_id={my_github_client_id}&client_secret={my_github_client_secret}", payload)

    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()

    print(data.decode("utf-8"))

    return None
```

But I keep getting:

```
error=bad_verification_code&error_description=The+code+passed+is+incorrect+or+expired.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors%2F%23bad-verification-code
```

I have double and triple checked the github client id and secret I am using and they are correct, Where am I going wrong?

Here is my call back page where I receieve and send the code to my backend

```
<template>
  <PageLayout v-if="error">
    <div class="content-layout">
      <h1 id="page-title" class="content__title">Error</h1>
      <div class="content__body">
        <p id="page-description">
          <span>{{ error.message }}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </PageLayout>
  <div class="page-layout" v-else>
    <NavBar />
    <MobileNavBar />
    <div class="page-layout__content" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onBeforeMount } from "vue";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { postProtectedResource } from "@/services/message.service";
import NavBar from "@/components/navigation/desktop/nav-bar.vue";
import MobileNavBar from "@/components/navigation/mobile/mobile-nav-bar.vue";
import PageLayout from "@/components/page-layout.vue";

const { error, getAccessTokenSilently, user } = useAuth0();
const route = useRoute()

const set_github_access = async (code, state) => {
  const access_token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
  const email = user.value.email;
  const payload = {
      "code": code,
      "state": state,
      "email": email,
  }
  const response = await postProtectedResource(
    "Users/save_github_cred",
    access_token,
    payload
  );
  console.log(response);
}

onBeforeMount(() => {
  console.log(route.query);
  const { code, state} = route.query;
  set_github_access(code, state);
})
</script>
```

Comment: client_id and secret aren't the problem, as the error points out, the `code` param is [bad](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/maintaining-oauth-apps/troubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors#bad-verification-code).  we would need to see how you request this code and how you send it to your backend to verify correctness.

Comment: yes, completely agree that is what it is saying. I am getting the code directly from https://www.callbackurl.com/login/callback?code=thecodefromauth0&state=statecode. I am sending this directly to the backend. I also copied and pasted this to postman and I get the same error. I am definitely not using a mistaken code.

Comment: it would be good to actually see the code rather than you describe it, you never know if there's a small error you've missed that someone else can point out, but have you verified the code sent to the backend is the exact same code received on the frontend?

Comment: ok I will add it to my question